# How to bind Lists of a custom view model to a dropDownList an get the selected value after POST in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, editorfor

I have following problem. In my view model I defined some list properties as follows:

```
public class BasketAndOrderSearchCriteriaViewModel
{
    List<KeyValuePair> currencies;
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair> Currencies
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.currencies == null)
                this.currencies = new List<KeyValuePair>();
            return this.currencies;
        }
    }

    List<KeyValuePair> deliverMethods;
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair> DeliveryMethods
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.deliverMethods == null)
                this.deliverMethods = new List<KeyValuePair>();
            return this.deliverMethods;
        }
    }
 }
```

This view model is embedded in another view model:

```
 public class BasketAndOrderSearchViewModel
 {
    public BasketAndOrderSearchCriteriaViewModel Criteria
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return this.criteria; }
    }
 }
```

I use 2 action methods; one is for the GET and the other for POST:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(BasketAndOrderSearchViewModel model){...}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSearch(BasketAndOrderSearchViewModel model){...}
```

In the view I implement the whole view model by using the EditorFor-Html Helper which does not want to automatically display DropDownLists for List properties!
**1. Question: How can you let EditorFor display DropDownLists?**

Since I could not figure out how to display DropDownLists by using EditorFor, I used the DropDownList Html helper and filled it through the view model as follows:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeliveryMethodAsSelectListItem()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = true,
            Text = "<Choose Delivery method>",
            Value = "0"
        });
        foreach (var item in this.DeliveryMethods)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = false,
                Text = item.Value,
                Value = item.Key
            });
        }

        return list;
    }
```

My 2. question: As you can see I pass my view model to the action metho with POST attribute! **Is there a way to get the selected value of a DropDownList get binded to the passed view model?** At the moment all the DropDownList are empty and the selected value can only be fetched by the Request.Form which I definitely want to avoid!

I would greatly appreciate some ideas or tips on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to take on this one:

**Answer to Question 1: How can you let EditorFor display DropDownLists?**

When you call `Html.EditorFor()` you can pass extra ViewData values to the EdiorTemplate View:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Criteria, new { DeliveryMethods = Model.DeliveryMethods, Currencies = Model.Currencies}) %>
```

Now you have `ViewData["DeliveryMethods"]` and `ViewData["Currencies"]` initialized and available inside your EditorTemplate.

In your `EditorTemplate` you somehow need to call and convert those entries into DropDowns / SelectLists.
Assuming you've got an ascx file of type `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<BasketAndOrderSearchCriteriaViewModel>` you could do the following:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryMethods) %>
<%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedDeliveryMethod", new SelectList(ViewData["DeliveryMethods"] as IEnumerable, "SelectedDeliveryMethod", "Key", "value", Model.SelectedDeliveryMethod)) %>
```

Same goes for the Currencies.

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Currencies) %>
<%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedCurrency", new SelectList(ViewData["Currencies"] as IEnumerable, "SelectedDeliveryMethod", "Key", "value", Model.SelectedCurrency)) %>
```

This setup will make your `DeliveryMethodAsSelectListItem()` obsolete and you can use *any* kind of list. Means you are not bound to KeyValuePairs. You'll just need to adjust your call on `Html.DropDownList()` from now on.

As you can see, I have introduced some new properties to your `BasketAndOrderSearchCriteriaViewModel`:

```
Model.SelectedDeliveryMethod
Model.SelectedCurrency
```

They are used to store the currently selected value.

**Answer to Question 2: Is there a way to get the selected value of a DropDownList get binded to the passed view model?**

In the EditorFor template we are passing the newly created `Model.SelectedDeliveryMethod` and `Model.SelectedCurrency` properties as the `SelectedValue Parameter` (See [4th Overload of the DropDownList Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx)).

Now that we have the View doing it's job: How can we get the currently selected value inside the **POST** Action?

This is really easy now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSearch(BasketAndOrderSearchViewModel model)
{
    ...
    var selectedDeliveryMethod = model.Criteria.SelectedDeliveryMethod;
    var selectedCurrency model.Criteria.SelectedDeliveryMethod;
    ...
}
```

Note: I don't have an IDE to test it right now, but it should do the trick or at least show you in which direction to go.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply to my question! It gave me a good hint in which direction I have to go! I will provide my final solution in here when it is done!

Answer (score 2):

For those like me that got to this post these days I'd recommend you to fully download the tutorial from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1 which covers this and most of the common techniques related with .NET MVC applications.

Anyway Really usefull your post and answers man (If I could vote you I would :)